# How to cast variables in python with jcc

Tags: java, python, casting, typing, jcc

In java it is possible to cast an object onto a class.
An good example is found here

```
Object aSentenceObject = "This is just a regular sentence";
String aSentenceString = (String)aSentenceObject;
```

I have a program that needs to integrate some java with python.  I am trying to do this via the [JCC library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/JCC/).  The problem that I am encountering is that with JCC, all of the java classes are loaded into the imported library that I created with JCC.  So I can create an instance of the base class by passing the necessary argument to the constructor of the java class.

```
obj = javaLibrary.BaseClass('foo')
```

However, in my code I need to be able to cast this object onto a a more “specific” type of Object.
How can I accomplish this in python with JCC?  It seems like it may be impossible because python is dynamically typed, but that is why I am asking this question.

Comment: Are you asking how to cast an object that you get from Java, from within python? You can't, and you don't need to. Just call the methods on the object in python. There's more info at https://lucene.apache.org/pylucene/jcc/features.html.

Comment: [link](http://lucene.apache.org/pylucene/jcc/readme.html) The docs say that it is possible.  "In Python each wrapped class has a class method called cast_ that implements the same functionality."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All comments above valid, but to be specific for your case:

```
casted_obj = Object.cast_(obj)
```